# Query the ranking list in Laravel 7

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-7

> i want to make a list of the top players in **Laraval 7**
>   And I need to display two rankings on the site
>   And there is a need for **2** queries
>
> > **1.** The first query based on the number of rows per user in the database table (including the number to be returned)
> >     **2.** The second query is based on the sum of the rake fields in the database table. (The sum must be returned)

### I need two queries to display these two ranking lists in Larval

---

[image: Table used]

Answer (score 0):

```
$top_hand_users = DB::table('hand_logs')
    ->whereIn('result', [
        'win',
        'lose'
    ])
    ->groupBy(['user_id'])
    ->get();
```